# output prints on the same line as hostname

Tags: python, hostname

I wrote a code using for loop that prints output on the same line. However, after executing the code a hostname displays on the same line as output. Is there any way to avoid it?

*Code*

```
list = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
for x in list:
    print(x, end='')
```

*Ouput*

```
hellohostname:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `print()` after your loop to add a newline to the output.